# How do I "associate an instance profile" with an environment on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to "associate an instance profile" with my environment (to speed up upload performance for my website) but can't find useful instructions on how anywhere in the AWS documentation (or here on SO).

How do I "associate an instance profile" with an environment on AWS?

Comment: FWIW, I'm uploading a Flask web application to EB and am getting very slow performance along with a warning: "The environment does not have an IAM instance profile associated with it. To improve deployment speed please associate an IAM instance profile with the environment."

Comment: Also, I've used `eb` to attach `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`, but that seems to have no effect (I still get the warning)?

Comment: Could you please explain detail on what's `associate an instance profile`, what do you want to do ? and do you plan to do something via awscli, SDK or from management console?

Comment: @BMW: No idea. I'm just looking for the steps needed to comply.

Comment: my question is, I didn't understand the word `associate` here in expression, what you need do for the instance profile? what profile are you talking about, is the profile reported by `ec2-metadata` command?

Comment: @BMW: Again: no idea — that's the question (or more precisely, why it's a question). I don't know what "associate" or "instance profile"  or precisely what "environment" mean. Just that I need to do it to get things working smoothly.

Comment: So if you can't explain the requirement clearly, we can't guess what you need. Maybe you need change the way to describe the problem by simply and clear way.

Comment: @BMW: The [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27734357/656912) is on the right track: it's pretty simple to understand, as you see. I'm merely (as the question states) trying to "associate an IAM instance profile with an environment". That's all. I'm seeking instructions on how to do that.

Comment: it explains the instance profile, and how to create, list, get, remove, etc. But what do you do for `associate`?And what's the relationship with upload performance.

Answer (score 5):

Not clear what you are trying to accomplish, but if you are look to just 'associate an instance profile', here you go:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/instance-profiles.html

> An instance profile is a container for an IAM role. Instance profiles
>   are used to pass role information to an Amazon EC2 instance when the
>   instance starts. When you use the Amazon EC2 console to launch an
>   instance with an IAM role, you can select a role to associate with the
>   instance. In the console, the list that's displayed is actually a list
>   of instance profile names.
>
> If you use the AWS Management Console to create a role, the console
>   creates an instance profile automatically and gives it the same name
>   as the role it corresponds to. However, if you use the CLI, API, the
>   AWS SDK, or a third-party tool to create roles and instance profiles,
>   you create the roles and instance profiles as separate actions, and
>   you might give them different names. In that case, you need to know
>   the names of your instance profiles as well as the names of roles they
>   contain so that you can choose the correct instance profile when you
>   launch an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I'm still not entirely clear on the steps though. Is there a better breakdown of them somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing this error when trying to set up a Elastic Beanstalk environment, it could be that the IAM user does not have sufficient permissions. You should add the IAM Policy named IAMFullAccess for that user.

Comment: Very late for this. But do not do that. Always minimum required permissions for the job required. FullAccess is the opposite of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can check one option that works here for AWS Beanstalk. This is using AWS Console.

1. Create IAM Role for "EC2" as AWS Service and attach
   "AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess" policy to it.
2. Create an AWS Beanstalk environment with tier/platform/application of choice. (I    did with Web Tier choosing Docker platform using python:3-onbuild).
3. Hit "Configure More Options" > "Modify" Security.
4. Choose "IAM instance profile" which was created in Step 1. (Keep Service role
   "aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role" as this is needed! It has some key policies!)
5. "Save" and "Create Environment".

Similarly, it should work for AWS CLI and AWS SDK as well. Key here is the instance profile role you choose for EC2 (or say instance IAM role/instance profile) during Beanstalk Environment creation.

You can create customer managed policy extending or reusing AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess policy based on need. Refer AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess to understand it better. Also, check out some more AWS Managed policies starting with AWSElasticBeanStalk*.

Somehow default aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role policy is not working/taking effect as desired for me.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the AWS console now displays an alert (see image) that has a link to help you associate the instance profile with your environment. Therefore, if you see this message in the CLI, you probably need to log into the Management Console, navigate to Elastic Beanstalk, and choose your environment. You will then see the message and be able to use the link to resolve the issue.

Note 1: You may need to redeploy your app after associating the profile. I did.

Note 2: It really does make deployments faster.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Orome,

As E.J Brennan pointed out in his post, you must have a role created first, and attach the necessary IAM policies to that role, then you create the instance profile:

aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name YOUR_INSTANCE_PROFILE_NAME

Then add the role you created in the beginning to the instance profile:

aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --instance-profile-name YOUR_INSTANCE_PROFILE_NAME --role-name YOUR_ROLE

Then attach the instance profile to your instance:
aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --instance-id YOUR_INSTANCE_ID --iam-instance-profile Name="YOUR_INSTANCE_PROFILE_NAME"

Is this what you are looking for?

As E.J Brennan also pointed out, the AWS management console does the instance profile for you behind the scenes.